# GeoTIFF Data Extraction

Tags: geotiff-tiff, metadata

Can a GeoTIFF have data like an attribute table in ESRI feature class or a .dbf file in shapefiles? I downloaded a dataset from here

https://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/download.php?ds=pop

which is a GeoTIFF. It comes with an Excel sheet expanding the different attributes/fields that were used to make this TIFF. There is also some data in the Excel. Could this data be part of the TIFF that I am failing to extract?

I made an extract for the whole world at 1KM resolution. The resulting zip contains a tif, ovr, pdf and excel

Comment: What kind of data exactly?

Comment: The excel sheet has fields such as Country, Administrative Division, Population density/km2 etc. I want to know if these fields listed in the excel that comes with the GeoTIFF download can be extracted to a table.
Also, I want to know on what value is the min-max based. I am unable to decipher this from the layer symbology in QGIS/ArcGIS

Comment: The method that was used for creating the raster is described in the PDF that is included in the same zip.  Probably producing exactly similar raster from the Excel is not very easy. I would find the referenced article first: "The disaggregation methodology is described in a peer reviewed paper (Freire et al., 2016)."

Comment: Hi user30184, I did go through the PDF and realized it was the method used to make the GeoTIFF however, I wished they had information on the final field that was used to create the tags. I'll look this up. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

TIFF file can contain metadata in the tags. What tags a TIFF file contains can be checked for example with a tiffinfo tool http://www.libtiff.org/man/tiffinfo.1.html. There are also more feature rich tools like Exiv2 https://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/wiki/The_Metadata_in_TIFF_files

```
tiffinfo GHS_POP_E2030_GLOBE_R2023A_54009_100_V1_0_R7_C18.tif

TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered.
=== TIFF directory 0 ===
TIFF Directory at offset 0x10 (16)
  Image Width: 10000 Image Length: 10000
  Tile Width: 256 Tile Length: 256
  Bits/Sample: 64
  Sample Format: IEEE floating point
  Compression Scheme: LZW
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Tag 33550: 100.000000,100.000000,0.000000
  Tag 33922: 0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,-1041000.000000,3000000.000000,0.000000
  Tag 34735: 1,1,0,10,1024,0,1,32767,1025,0,1,1,1026,34737,16,0,2048,0,1,4326,2049,34737,7,16,2054,0,1,9102,2057,34736,1,1,2059,34736,1,0,3073,34737,328,23,3076,0,1,9001
  Tag 34736: 298.257224,6378137.000000
  Tag 34737: World_Mollweide|WGS 84|ESRI PE String = PROJCS["World_Mollweide",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mollweide"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]|
  GDAL NoDataValue: -200
  Predictor: none 1 (0x1)
```

This image has only standard TIFF tags and a few GeoTIFF tags which are reported as unknown. You must keep the Excel file as a source of the metadata.

Comment: Hi user30184, Thank you. I also think this tiff has not a lot of data attached to it. The excel is probably all the data that was aggregated to make this tiff to get the population density. I just wanted to know which field (from the excel) was used to make the tags. This is population density so my guess is "average Populated Area km2". However, I am not sure at all. Is there a way to check that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't mention software, but in ArcGIS there is a tool [Build Raster Attribute Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm) that does this for GeoTIFFs.

If you can expand beyond GeoTIFF, the KEA format is worth considering. It has excellent support for raster attribute tables (RATs), as it is built on top of HD5. http://kealib.org/ But writing the table is more involved than the ArcGIS tool. If you install GDAL with conda (conda-forge channel), it comes with the KEA driver. Then installing tuiview from conda (conda-forge as well) gives you a lightweight KEA viewer that supports interrogation of the RAT: http://tuiview.org/

QGIS also supports reading a RAT for a KEA file, through a plugin.

Comment: Hi alphabetasoup, Thank you for all the tips. I'll look them up :) Unfortunately, the field that is used in the GeoTIFF is a non integer and the tool you mention works on only integer based fields. I am trying to find other datasets but the Global Human Settlement (from where I downloaded) has only GeoTIFF is the datatype.